# has_one through и алиас в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель `Company`

Есть модель `PaymentInfo`

Есть модель `User`

`@company.users` возвращает список сотрудников компании, связь один-ко-многим.

Нужно построить связь так:
`@company.payer`, где `payer` - это инстанс модель `User`. здесь нужна связь один-к-одному через третью таблицу, но у меня не выходит правильно построить связь. У одной Company может быть только 1 Payer, у одного 1 Payer может быть только 1 Company

делаю так:

1) миграция

```
class AddPayerToPaymentInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :payment_infos, :payer, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end
```

2) модель User

```
belongs_to :payment_info
```

3) модель PaymentInfo

```
belongs_to :company
has_one    :payer
```

еще пробовал так:

```
belongs_to :company
has_one    :payer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'payer_id'
```

4) модель Company

```
has_many :users
has_one  :payer, through: :payment_info
```

Comment: Вы говорите, что нужна связь "многие-ко-многим", но используете belongs_to/has_one и `payer` в единственном числе. Объясните подробнее про соотношение company и payer.  У компании их тоже много, или всё-таки он только один? У payer тоже может быть несколько компаний?

Comment: У одной `Company` может быть только 1 `Payer`
у одного 1 `Payer` может быть только 1 `Company`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать:

модель PaymentInfo должна быть связана через `belongs_to`, вы же в ней храните `payer_id`

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :payer, class_name: 'User'
```

модель User

```
has_one :payment_info
has_one :paid_company, through: :payment_info
```

модель Company

```
has_many :users
has_one :payment_info
has_one :payer, through: :payment_info
```